# Can I download windows updates automatically during the night?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-update

I would like to download the windows 2003/8 updates during the night. Is it possible ? But How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want.

Open up Registry editor and make these changes:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\ScheduledInstallDay=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\ScheduledInstallTime=23
This will automatically update at 11PM every night.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: That's wonderful!!!

Comment: Just read through the other options in the link to make sure you don't have any other settings to change.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend (if you haven't already) deploying a WSUS server. This way you can perform sync with windows update during the night. Group Policy can be used to schedule installation.

If you're not using a domain then look at the options available in local group policy using gpedit.msc on each of the servers. Most of the options are for scheduling the installation of updates (not download). You can however configure the frequency with which windows checks for available updates which might be helpful to you.

Perhaps you could provide some details of your environment so that we might advise you further.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called "WSUS Offline" that provides a tool that you can use to download all Windows and Office patches and build a CDROM ISO with them which can then be used to update a Window machine offline, without Internet/WSUS connectivity.
This is probably what you are looking at, right?!

See http://www.wsusoffline.net/